# Dosen't show all the specific data of array

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array of words stored in the variable `$tags`.

```
  print_r($tags);

     Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [token] => Facebooks
        [tag] => NNS
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [token] => new
        [tag] => JJ

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [token] => Slingshot
        [tag] => NN

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [token] => messaging
        [tag] => VBG
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [token] => app
        [tag] => NNP

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [token] => the
        [tag] => DT
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [token] => one
        [tag] => NN
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [token] => that
        [tag] => IN
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [token] => forces
        [tag] => NNS
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [token] => friendship
        [tag] => NN

    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [token] => through
        [tag] => IN
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [token] => a
        [tag] => DT
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [token] => special
        [tag] => JJ
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [token] => reciprocation
        [tag] => NN
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [token] => mechanic
        [tag] => NN

    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [token] => has
        [tag] => VBZ
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [token] => today
        [tag] => NN
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [token] => launched
        [tag] => VBN
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [token] => worldwide.
        [tag] => JJ
    )
```

)

im trying to extract only the arrays witch contain `[tag] => NN` and remove the others using this:

```
$kali = array("NN");

echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';

 foreach ( $tags as $k => $array ) {
 if ( $array['tag'] != $kali[0] ) 
        {
    unset($tags[$k]);
        }
   }

   print_r($tags);
```

this is the output:

```
      Array
    (
[6] => Array
    (
        [token] => one
        [tag] => NN
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [token] => reciprocation
        [tag] => NN
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [token] => today
        [tag] => NN
    )

    )
```

the questing is what i did wrong?? why dost show all the arrays but only 3 of them??

in this example in total are 6 and it shows on 3. why?

Comment: Instead of removing them from the `$tags` array try adding just those rows to an new array.

Comment: show me how to do that

Comment: try `if ( trim($array['tag']) != trim($kali[0]) )`, did it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `spaces` or special characters like `\n` or `\r` are added to the end of the string, so comparing the string with another will evaluate the especial characters as well. In order to skip them, you need to `trim` the string then compare it.

**Example**

```
if ( trim($array['tag']) != trim($kali[0]) )
{
 // code goes here
}
```